# How do you track employee working hours?

Tags: time-management, tracking, timekeeping

I've inherited the responsibility of managing a team in my role. I need to track the hours that each employee spends on each project. We're a small startup that lacks an existing process for this task. I know there are a number of tools for this, but I'd appreciate a guide/recommendation if you have one.

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to PM.SE. As your question stands, it's [off-topic](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site as software recommendation questions tend to become obsolete pretty quickly. As a suggestion, would be interesting to delve into the reasons why time tracking is required in your company. It might be for billing purposes, which goes into the realm of "product / company / vendor management" and thus beyond the domain of project management _per se_.

Comment: You might want to try on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ even though a shared Google spreadsheet can do the trick just fine. But as Tiago mentioned, it would be more interesting to know the reasons of why you want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deputy is wildly popular for this very purpose and has a nice writeup here:

https://www.deputy.com/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-employee-time-tracking-and-timesheet-software

In our office we use their enterprise solution to manage our teams and integrate with payroll, and I am happy to recommend them.